# How to create an grid in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I am creating an app where I want to create an user grid which is shown below. 
Here is the code that I tried to implement it.

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="HomeController">
<div class="container">
<div class="user" ng-repeat="user in users">
<span class="person"> {{ users.person }}</span>
<span class="title"> {{ users.title }}</span>
<span class="date"> {{ users.date }}</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: My issue is,  I can't figure it out to write a grid that is shown in the image

Comment: This seems less an Angular question and more a CSS question

Comment: no, its not a css question though. How can you implement to show a grid to look like the image? ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an Angular or Javascript problem.  I suggest to KISS (Keep It Simple Silly).  No need to pull in libraries, jQuery, Material, Bootstrap and the rest of the kitchen for this.

(Obviously adjust CSS for your needs. This is just a demo.)

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl">
  <section ng-repeat="person in $ctrl.people" class="person">
    <figure class="person__image"><img ng-src="{{ ::person.img }}"></figure>
    <div class="person__data">
      <h4 ng-bind="::person.name"></h4>
      <small ng-bind="::person.date"></small>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.person {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.person__image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.people = [
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      img: '//placehold.it/100x100',
      date: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'Mary',
      img: '//placehold.it/100x100',
      date: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'Same',
      img: '//placehold.it/100x100',
      date: new Date()
    }
  ]
});
```

Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fdMs46B4bo58Bi7Y4VyF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-material with angular to replicate the same and use md-list-item

```
<md-content>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="null">
            <img ng-src="{{user.person}}?{{$index}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}" />
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{ user.who }}</h3>
              <h4>{{ user.title }}</h4>
              <p>{{ user.date }}</p>
            </div>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-divider inset></md-divider>
        </md-list>
      </md-content>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fwt0yt?p=preview)**

```js
angular.module('webapp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
      $scope.users.push({
        person: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/598463?v=3&s=60',
        title: "Brunch this weekend?",
        date: new Date()
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="webapp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hammerjs/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div layout="column" layout-fill flex style="max-height:100%">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <div flex="50">
          <h3 class="title"><span>Users List</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div flex layout="column" style="position:relative">
      <md-content>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="null">
            <img ng-src="{{user.person}}?{{$index}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}" />
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{ user.who }}</h3>
              <h4>{{ user.title }}</h4>
              <p>{{ user.date }}</p>
            </div>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-divider inset></md-divider>
        </md-list>
      </md-content>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show me some code by applying to the image. So, I can have a sense. I said earlier in the question I am new to Angular.

Comment: @VADEV did it help